# Notify server that client system shut down

Tags: client, server, shutdown, vaadin7

I have a situation where I need to know that client system has shut down manually or due to power failure (irrespective of same LAN or wide network).

I need to know that after logging in to my application (web), client forget to logout and shut down his system manually or due to power failure.

I'm storing logged in users status in a HashMap not in DB and removing when clicking logout button....

If system got shut down without logging out that is not removing from the HashMap. Is there any event listener in Java to catch client shut down status?

How can I achieve this scenario, is this possible?

I'm using Vaadin 7.4.3 as a framework for my web application.

Comment: Thanks for editing Marc....

Answer (score 0):

Add a session destroy listener to your web application and remove the user there. The session destroy listener will be called when session expires. Actually you should implement the logout button that way that it invalidates the session so the only place where you need to remove users is this session destroy listener.

Comment: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/139230/7457752........this link helped me thanks Henri for your help u made my day...:)

Comment: It is taking half an hour for session to destroy....till then he can't able to login...is there any other way, other than setting session time to less?

Comment: @CaliCo You can define session timeout smaller, for example 15min. Can't you just remove the user from database when he logins again and allow login that way?

Comment: If it is by storing in DB also, after session close only the value will be updated in Db right?